# iOS Swift Implementation of Instagram Story Editor

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, instagram, avplayer

I'm working on a project similar to editing photos/videos on Instagram Story (with the functionality of adding stickers, etc). My initial approach was to use

videoCompositionInstructions!.animationTool = AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool(postProcessingAsVideoLayer: videoLayer, in: containerLayer)

but I realized that there are many challenges with this method. First, if the input is a landscape video, I cannot recover the background gradient color - it becomes all black (https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8cUh.jpg). Not to mention the cropping issues - if the user moves the video out of bounds, the video should be clipped, but with my current approach, this would be difficult. Also, if I add stickers, I have to scale the x and y to fit the render size of the video.

What really would be the best approach to this? Surely there would be an easier way? Intuitively, it would make sense to start off with a container view and the user can add stickers, video, etc to it and it would be the easiest to simply export the container view with clipsToBounds = true (no need to scale x/y, crop the video, landscape issues, etc).

If anyone has worked on a similar project, or has any inputs, it would be appreciated.

```
class AVFoundationClient {


var selectedVideoURL: URL?
var mutableComposition: AVMutableComposition?
var videoCompositionInstructions: AVMutableVideoComposition?
var videoTrack: AVMutableCompositionTrack?
var sourceAsset: AVURLAsset?
var insertTime = CMTime.zero
var sourceVideoAsset: AVAsset?
var sourceVideoTrack: AVAssetTrack?
var sourceRange: CMTimeRange?
var renderWidth: CGFloat?
var renderHeight: CGFloat?
var endTime: CMTime?
var videoBounds: CGRect?

var stickerLayers = [CALayer]()

func exportVideoFileFromStickersAndOriginalVideo(_ stickers: [Int:Sticker], sourceURL: URL) {

    createNewMutableCompositionAndTrack()
    getSourceAssetFromURL(sourceURL)
    getVideoParamsAndAppendTracks()
    createVideoCompositionInstructions()

    for (_, sticker) in stickers {
        createStickerLayer(sticker.image!, x: sticker.x!, y: sticker.y!, width: sticker.width!, height: sticker.height!, scale: sticker.scale!)
    }

    mergeStickerLayersAndFinalizeInstructions()
    export(mutableComposition!)

}

func createStickerLayer(_ image: UIImage, x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat, width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat, scale: CGFloat) {

    let scaleRatio = renderWidth!/UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    let stickerX = x*scaleRatio
    let stickerY = y*scaleRatio

    let imageLayer = CALayer()
    imageLayer.frame = CGRect(x: stickerX, y: stickerY, width: width*scaleRatio, height: height*scaleRatio)
    imageLayer.contents = image.cgImage
    imageLayer.contentsGravity = CALayerContentsGravity.resize
    imageLayer.masksToBounds = true

    stickerLayers.append(imageLayer)
}

func mergeStickerLayersAndFinalizeInstructions() {

    let videoLayer = CALayer()
    videoLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: renderWidth!, height: renderWidth!*16/9)
    videoLayer.contentsGravity = .resizeAspectFill

    let containerLayer = CALayer()
    containerLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.mainBlue().cgColor
    containerLayer.isGeometryFlipped = true
    containerLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: renderWidth!, height: renderWidth!*16/9)
    containerLayer.addSublayer(videoLayer)
    for stickerLayer in stickerLayers {
        containerLayer.addSublayer(stickerLayer)
    }

    videoCompositionInstructions!.animationTool = AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool(postProcessingAsVideoLayer: videoLayer, in: containerLayer)

}


func createNewMutableCompositionAndTrack() {
    mutableComposition = AVMutableComposition()
    videoTrack = mutableComposition!.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video, preferredTrackID: CMPersistentTrackID())
}

func getSourceAssetFromURL(_ fileURL: URL) {
    sourceAsset = AVURLAsset(url: fileURL, options: nil)
}

func getVideoParamsAndAppendTracks() {
    let sourceDuration = CMTimeRangeMake(start: CMTime.zero, duration: sourceAsset!.duration)

    sourceVideoTrack = sourceAsset!.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video)[0]
    renderWidth = sourceVideoTrack!.renderSize().width
    renderHeight = sourceVideoTrack!.renderSize().height
    endTime = sourceAsset!.duration
    sourceRange = sourceDuration

    do {
        try videoTrack!.insertTimeRange(sourceDuration, of: sourceVideoTrack!, at: insertTime)
    }catch {
        print("error inserting time range")
    }
}

func createVideoCompositionInstructions() {
    let mainInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
    mainInstruction.timeRange = sourceRange!

    let videolayerInstruction = videoCompositionInstruction(videoTrack!, asset: sourceAsset!)
    videolayerInstruction.setOpacity(0.0, at: endTime!)

    //Add instructions
    mainInstruction.layerInstructions = [videolayerInstruction]
    videoCompositionInstructions = AVMutableVideoComposition()
    videoCompositionInstructions!.renderScale = 1.0
    videoCompositionInstructions!.renderSize = CGSize(width: renderWidth!, height: renderWidth!*16/9)
    videoCompositionInstructions!.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(value: 1, timescale: 30)
    videoCompositionInstructions!.instructions = [mainInstruction]
}

func videoCompositionInstruction(_ track: AVCompositionTrack, asset: AVAsset)
    -> AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction {
        let instruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: track)
        let assetTrack = asset.tracks(withMediaType: .video)[0]
    instruction.setTransform(assetTrack.preferredTransform.concatenating(CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: -(renderHeight! - renderWidth!*16/9)/2)), at: CMTime.zero)

        return instruction
}

}
extension AVFoundationClient {


//Export the AV Mutable Composition
func export(_ mutableComposition: AVMutableComposition) {
    // Set up exporter
    guard let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: mutableComposition, presetName: AVAssetExportPreset1920x1080) else { return }
    exporter.outputURL = generateExportUrl()
    exporter.outputFileType = AVFileType.mov
    exporter.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = false
    exporter.videoComposition = videoCompositionInstructions
    exporter.exportAsynchronously() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.exportDidComplete(exportURL: exporter.outputURL!, doneEditing: false)
        }
    }
}

func generateExportUrl() -> URL {

    // Create a custom URL using curernt date-time to prevent conflicted URL in the future.
    let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
    let dateFormat = DateFormatter()
    dateFormat.dateStyle = .long
    dateFormat.timeStyle = .short
    let dateString = dateFormat.string(from: Date())
    let exportPath = (documentDirectory as NSString).strings(byAppendingPaths: ["edited-video-\(dateString).mp4"])[0]
    //erase old
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    do {
        try fileManager.removeItem(at: URL(fileURLWithPath: exportPath))
    } catch {
        print("Unable to remove item at \(URL(fileURLWithPath: exportPath))")
    }

    return URL(fileURLWithPath: exportPath)
}

//Export Finish Handler
func exportDidComplete(exportURL: URL, doneEditing: Bool) {
    PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
        PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: exportURL)
    }) { saved, error in
        if saved {print("successful saving")}
        else {
            print("error saving")
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: have you figured this out